# Jquery clone of a textbox without the content

Tags: jquery

Can I clone one textbox without its content??Means if I enter some values in the textbox after cloning I want an empty textbox.Is it possible?Or jquery clone returns this as an innerHtml?

Comment: By textbox do you mean textarea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, cloning copies the value with the `<input>` currently has, but you can just clear it when cloning, for example:

```
var clone = $(".myInput").clone(true).val("");
```

Based off your comment, you'd need something like this when cloning the row:

```
var newRow = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true).appendTo('table')
                                  .find('input').val('');
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `true` add, when used with `clone()`?

Comment: @David - it copies event handlers/data the element may have...so for example if there's a `keyup` handler, etc...without `true` none of that would copy over.

Comment: @OddOneOut, I'm sure you're welcome, but I had nothing to do with it; all the thanks to @Nick Craver =) ...and, in that vein, thanks for the explanation, Nick; I could've read the api, but...um. I was being a little lazy, maybe? =b

Answer (score 2):

Just set the value of the cloned textbox to an empty string, like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="source" type="textbox" value="Some text..." />
<div id="target"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#source").clone().val("").appendTo("#target");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/X5x4L/

**Edit:** Works with textarea aswell, see: http://jsfiddle.net/X5x4L/1/

Comment: var newRow = 
            $(this)
                 .closest('tr')
                 .clone(true)
     .val("")
                 .appendTo('table');

Comment: @OddOneOut: Ok? Is that your code? Isn't it working? Just don't drop some code...

Comment: @OddOneOut: In what context? And that is not an input your are trying to clone, that's a table row.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a lot of fields in the form, so to make all them null after clonning:

```
$('.user-address:first').clone().appendTo('.user-addresses');
$('.user-address:last').find('[name]').val(null);
```

Hole helps someone.