# .clone() method in jquery without copying value

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery clone of a textbox without the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366159/jquery-clone-of-a-textbox-without-the-content)

I use `.clone` in jQuery. When I clone ul it is cloning its value also. I only want to copy structure not value. When you type some value in input field and then click clone it will clone input value too.

[Here is my code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/vhq5p/):

```
<div class="str">
    <ul><li><input type="text" /></li></ul>
</div>
<a href="#">clone</a>

$(function() {
    $('a').live('click', function() {
        var cln = $('ul:last').clone();
        $('.str').append(cln);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try the code below. By the way, if you use the last version of jQuery I'd suggest using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead of `live` (here instead of `body` you can use any parent of `a` element).

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function() {
    $("ul:last").clone().appendTo(".str").find("input[type='text']").val("");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vhq5p/18/

Comment: You're welcome, sorry, just a note, isn't `find("input[type='text']")` faster?

Comment: @undefined Accordingly to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) seems to be faster. However, it doesn't solve the problem with non-specified `type` attribute. So fwiw this deprecation is not that good :/

Comment: You are correct, using `input` before the `[type='text']` makes it more faster.

Comment: Warning, this doesn't clear all form elements, particularly SELECTs, checked input boxes (radios, checkboxes), or TEXTAREAs.

Comment: @yahermann Yes, it doesn't. But if you need to, simply replace `input[text='text']` with `:input` selector. This will select all form fields including textareas, selects and all input elements.

Answer (score 13):

Do you mean:

```
var cln= $("ul:last").clone().find("input").val("").end();
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhq5p/12/)

Comment: Just a question, what does .end() do?

Comment: @NicolasHanna It is hard to explain in a comment. The docs (https://api.jquery.com/end/) explain it pretty well, specially when seeing examples. In this example you don't need to use the .end() because you are not chaining anything else after.