# Javascript clone without values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, function

After using `clone()` it cloning fields with values. I need to clone duplicate fields without values.

Javascript function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".add-row" ).click(function(){
      $( "ul.sea-service" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".personal-details1" );
   });
});
```

Also I've tried to add `.val("")` in following, but also unsuccessfully:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".add-row" ).click(function(){
      $( "ul.sea-service" ).first().clone().val("").appendTo( ".personal-details1" );
   });
});
```

Have you any ideas?

Here is **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c68jo3kr/)**, try to enter any values and press `+`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035910/clone-method-in-jquery-without-copying-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery clone of a textbox without the content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366159/jquery-clone-of-a-textbox-without-the-content)

Comment: Place `.val("")` in the end of expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.find('input').val('')` like following.

```
$( ".add-row" ).click(function(){
  $( "ul.sea-service" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".personal-details1" ).find('input').val('');
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c68jo3kr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to find the inputs and empty them

```
$( "ul.sea-service" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".personal-details1" ).find('input').val("");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c68jo3kr/2/

Comment: This is not working... Give some input an then clone. As per your answer the value will persist.

Comment: .find('input').val('') at the end does the job