# clone input without its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to clone a div and don't want to get the value of cloned input using jquery and ejs..the problem is when I create the array when in the cloned div I get everything ok except the time input I hot the second input only I want to get the value of third time for example

I've tried to empty the value of time input like this [Javascript clone without values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540490/javascript-clone-without-values) but it doesn't work.

```
var state ='', type='', time= '';
  $('#state').change(function () {
     state = this.value;
  })
  $('#type').change(function () {
     type = this.value;
  })

  $('#addToilet').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log( $('#toiletTime').val());
          time = '';
          $('#toiletContent').clone(true).appendTo('.another');
           time = $("#toiletTime").val();
           console.log(state);
             toilet.push({state, type, time});
             console.log('kk',toilet);
    },100)
})
```

my HTML:

```
 <label>Toilet State</label>
          <select class="form-control col-md-6" id="state" name="">
            <option disabled selected>Select the State..</option>
            <option value="Urine">Urine</option>
            <option value="Stool">Stool</option>
          </select>
          <label>Time</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control col-md-6" id="toiletTime" name="" value="">
          <label>Type</label>
          <select class="form-control col-md-6" id="type" name="">
            <option disabled selected>Select the Type..</option>
            <option value="Kind">Kind</option>
          </select>
       </div>
     </div>
  <div class="another">
    <p class="addNew" hidden>Add Another One</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

flush the value after cloning

```
$('#toiletContent').clone(true).val('').appendTo('.another');
```

better if you put the cloned item into a var and after append it

```
var clonedItem = $('#toiletContent').clone(true);

clonedItem.val('').appendTo('.another');
```

Comment: the problem is i cloned all the elements in the div and want to get the time value when i cloned it..it doen't work

Comment: @EmanEmad wait a second, you want to get a timestamp of the moment you clone the objects?

Comment: no i want to get the value that i inserted in cloned input even if i clone it for 4 times

Comment: @EmadEmad store the value into a var and assign it to cloned item before append  `clonedItem.val(your_value) .appendTo('.another')` any times you need

Comment: I've tried this but when I log the value when I do that it returns empty..I need the value that I inserted in the input text

Comment: if you clone and append the same input you get a multipe elements with non-unique id, so when you try to get the value jQuery return the value of the first input in DOM with that id.